# Laravel - Conditional Route Name mapping / dynamic routes

Tags: php, laravel

I thought to write static routes like contact, imprint or "About Us" in the web.php as a one-liner. I saw this at Laravel Daily.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/{page}', App\Http\Controllers\StaticPageController::class)
->name('page')
->where('page', 'about-us|imprint|contact');
```

It's nice but I'm getting problems with my navbar.
My Blade navbar has a dynamic part. The current menu item is highlighted. Very simple.

**nav.blade.php**

```
<x-nav-link :href="route('about-us')" :active="request()->routeIs('about-us')">
  {{ __('About us') }}
</x-nav-link>
```

With the new one-liner, I then get the following error message:

*Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException.
Route [about-us] not defined. (View: /project01/resources/views/includes/nav.blade.php)*

Which is logical, because I no longer have the about-us route.

Actually, the route should be given a corresponding array mapping. But I don't know how. How can I solve the problem?

---

**The solution for this problem will be:**

```
<x-nav-link :href="route('page', ['page' => 'about-us'])" :active="request()->routeIs('about-us')">
  {{ __('About us') }}
</x-nav-link>
```

**Special Thanks for all good answears!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

**1-** Change the `routeIs()` to `is()` and use the path, not the route name

```
<x-nav-link :href="route('page', ['page' => 'about-us'])" :active="request()->is('about-us/*')">
  {{ __('About us') }}
</x-nav-link>
```

**2-** Switch back to 3 routes instead of the one liner. There is no gain in using the one liner. It is slower and harder to read (maintain)

Comment: Options 1 and 2 It sound good! I prefer 2. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned a name `page` to a given route with the required parameter named `page`. So, you must use the following code:

```
route('page', ['page' => 'about-us']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: in combination with the answear from N69S it will works fine. thx.
```
<x-nav-link :href="route('page', ['page' => 'about-us'])" :active="request()->is('about-us/*')">
  {{ __('About us') }}
</x-nav-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding.**'about-us|imprint|contact'** is the parameter restrictions.**'page'** is the route name.So this should work;

```
<x-nav-link :href="route('page','about-us')" :active="Request::url() == route('page','about-us')">
    {{ __('About us') }}
</x-nav-link>
```

Comment: Yes that correct. See the comment bellow in Thân LƯƠNG answear. I allready edited above and waiting for approvment.